# Javascript scroll to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am adding dynamic div element with id 'newid' and using another button, i am trying to scroll to that dynamic element. After adding few dynamic elements, when i press the scroll button, i am scrolled to the end (last div element) but it stops working. My overall goal for this testing is to scroll to a dynamic added element. I dont have basics to move on, so please someone help me in the right direction.

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="myfunction()">test</button> <button onclick="addElement()">Add Element</button>


<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odit, ipsa aspernatur reiciendis facere labore accusamus architecto perspiciatis minus ad perferendis, illo nisi doloribus id quidem corporis blanditiis vel itaque!</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odit, ipsa aspernatur reiciendis facere labore accusamus architecto perspiciatis minus ad perferendis, illo nisi doloribus id quidem corporis blanditiis vel itaque!</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odit, ipsa aspernatur reiciendis facere labore accusamus architecto perspiciatis minus ad perferendis, illo nisi doloribus id quidem corporis blanditiis vel itaque!</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odit, ipsa aspernatur reiciendis facere labore accusamus architecto perspiciatis minus ad perferendis, illo nisi doloribus id quidem corporis blanditiis vel itaque!</div>



<div id="demo">Test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction ()  { 
    document.getElementById('newid').scrollIntoView();
    //alert("test");

}

function addElement() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.id = "newid";
      document.body.appendChild(element);

     element.appendChild(document.createTextNode
     ('New id'));
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try using the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library.  It will make your life much easier.  Also, you should try to avoid having multiple elements with the same ID.  ID's should be unique.  Try setting the ID to be unique, but each object has the same class attribute.

Comment: Agree woith @steinmas about ID's but for something this simple I don't think you need jQuery.  Your code worked for me or, at least, what I thought your question was....  I click add element a few times then click test.  It scrolls to newest element.  I add a few more and it scrolls to the last one added.  Is this not the expected functionality?

Comment: Hi Gary, add like 40-50 elements and it will stop scrolling to the last element. Also i am using above code just for understanding, please help me or guide me how to scroll to the dynamically added element, without using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunction ()  { 
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.myclass');
    nodes[nodes.length-1].scrollIntoView();
}

function addElement() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className ='myclass';
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New div'));
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

This code worked for me no matter how many I added. No jQuery needed.

Comment: Extraordinary Gary, it really worked. Can you please help me understand how this worked ? i am quite newbie when it comes to scrolling ? i tried different examples of scrollintoview already present on stackoverflow but none of them worked after adding lets say 40-50 elements, yours did, please help me understand and guide to some document for reference

Comment: The only thing I can think of was that you were using non-unique `id`'s.  There should only be one instance of an ID per page.  Classes, by definition, can be re-used over and over;  That's what they are for.

Comment: The only other thing I changed was to append the textNode to the new `div` before appending it to the body element.  Also I made sure to grab the last instance of the `div.myclass` before calling the `scrollIntoView` method.